# How do I Integrate Coveralls to An Open-Source Project?

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, travis-ci, coveralls

I want to contribute to an open-source project (specifically, [this one](https://github.com/kamranzafar/jtar)) where the project owner has already set up Travis. I want to integrate Coveralls to this project and send a pull-request. When I own the project, the process is simple:

- Configure build/test system with `.travis.yml` and language specific tools
- Take `repoToken` from Coveralls
- Add `repoToken` as environment variable to project's Travis system
- Add language specific configuration to `.travis.yml`'s `after_success` cycle.

However, I've got problems with that when I do not own the repository.

- Since I do not own the repository, I only can add project on Coveralls with my fork copy. What I mean is, my fork's coverage URL will be `/github/myusername/forkedrepo` in Coveralls and when I sent that PR to repository owner, it will be the same whereas it must be `/github/ownersusername/originalrepo`.
- I cannot add environment variable `repoToken` to owner's Travis build system since I do not own it.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to automatize this process? Like merging my forked Travis system to owner's original system for `repoToken` environment variable and/or creating a Coveralls system for owner?
- Or should I simply contact the owner, create separate Travis/Coveralls for my forked project by myself and leave some to-dos in codebase so that he can find these and change later?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- Java
- Maven
- Covertura Maven Plugin for coverage
- Coveralls Maven Plugin for sending coverage results to Coveralls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to modify your own pom.xml according to the coverage tool you'd like to use see https://github.com/trautonen/coveralls-maven-plugin for some explanation.

**You can avoid to put the repo token in the pom.xml file that you publish on github!**

Instead you can run the coverage report from the command line.

Here is a small helper script that will allow to run converalls from the command line. Just put your token in a place like $HOME/.coveralls or any similar location.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2019-06-26
# create test coverage report for coveralls
tokenpath=$HOME/.coveralls/coveralls.token
if [ ! -f $tokenpath ]
then
  echo "Script needs coveralls token in $tokenpath to work" 1>&2
  echo "Script can only be run successfully by project admins" 1>&2
  echo "see https://github.com/trautonen/coveralls-maven-plugin" 1>&2
  exit 1
else
  token=$(cat $tokenpath)
  # comment out to use jacoco
  #mvn clean test jacoco:report coveralls:report -D jacoco=true -DrepoToken=$token
  # comment out to use cobertura
  mvn cobertura:cobertura coveralls:report -DrepoToken=$token
fi
```

**Update**
Here is a version using the COVERALLS_TOKEN environment variable:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2019-06-26
# create test coverage report for coveralls

# is the environment variable not set?
if [ "$COVERALLS_TOKEN" = "" ]
then
  tokenpath=$HOME/.dukes/coveralls.token
  if [ ! -f $tokenpath ]
  then
    echo "Script needs coveralls token in $tokenpath to or COVERALLS_TOKEN environment variable to work" 1>&2
    echo "Script can only be run successfully by project admins" 1>&2
    echo "see https://github.com/trautonen/coveralls-maven-plugin" 1>&2
    echo "see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56815300/1497139" 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi
else
  export COVERALLS_TOKEN=$(cat $tokenpath)
fi
# the jacoco variable tries triggering a profile - check your pom.xml
# for any profile being in use
mvn clean test jacoco:report coveralls:report -D jacoco=true
#mvn clean test jacoco:report coveralls:report -D jacoco=true -DrepoToken=$token
#mvn cobertura:cobertura coveralls:report
#mvn cobertura:cobertura coveralls:report -DrepoToken=$COVERALLS_TOKEN
```

Comment: Wow, I have really forgotten about *this question*. It's been a year, I think and I know how to do this, but since I forgot this question, I haven't written an answer here. | By the way, if you add `COVERALLS_TOKEN` to environment variables, you do not have to put `-DrepoToken` to args. Actually, it is much safer to do it with environment variables because CI platforms can obscure sensitive data such as tokens from build logs in (especially open source) projects.